# How to know in object in java support clone in run time?

Tags: java, reflection, clone, copy-constructor

how to know if an object in java support clone ? or it has copy C'tor ? in run time

please provide an example ,
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if supports clone check

```
if(myObject instanceof Cloneable) {

}
```

The above will tell you if the object implements Cloneable and default clone is supported or not.

But there are cases when classes dont support clone method but they provide you with some API which will create a copy of the instance, for such methods you will have to look at the API documentation or source code.

Update : Why instanceof check doesn't guarantee a successful clone:

```
if(myObject instanceof Cloneable) { 
    Object obj = myObject.clone(); 
}
```

1-> Consider the below code snippet

```
public class IImplementCloneableButThrowException implements Cloneable{

    //Javadoc has a separate section for Exception, implementation like 
    //this and should clearly specify the condition in which 
    //CloneNotSupportedException will be thrown. 
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        //I implement but still wont clone, may be in future will allow myself to be cloned
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException("Sorry I cannot be cloned!");
    }
}
```

2-> Consider the 2nd case below

```
public class IImplementCloneableButCloneIsHidden implements Cloneable{
    //Ouch either no clone method or one which is Object class but that
    //has protected access modifier, which means I cannot call unless 
    //I extend it, too bad
}
```

So though `instanceof` check will pass correcltly either `clone` cannot be called or `clone` will throw exception.

Comment: is there a way to know in run time if copy C'tor exists ?

Comment: No, there isn't.  Reflection-based approaches have a significant risk of false positives -- just because there's a constructor that takes the same class as an argument doesn't mean that's a copy constructor, even setting aside copy factory methods and the like.  The only way to reliably tell if a constructor is a "copy constructor" is to read its documentation.

Comment: This check is quite insufficient though - there's no guarantee whatsoever that just because the object implements `Cloneable` that there's a public `clone` method available. So we still have to use reflection to call clone which is frankly horribly ugly.

Comment: Agreed but this check will ensure that you dont get ClassCastException, this check will not even guarantee safety from CloneNotSupportedException as the class implementing cloneable can still throw CloneNotSupportedException

Comment: `if(myObject instanceof Cloneable) {
 Object obj = myObject.clone();
}`
what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: @mprabhat in this case how can I be implement this, i want to check if an Object class support clone in "run time" (it doesn't has to clone, but the method clone should be called whatever it does) ?

Comment: If you have to called clone method then first check if it implements Cloneable and then use reflection to call clone, as it may be hidden

Answer (score -1):

All objects that support `clone` are supposed to also implement [`Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html).